# Write a double integral for surface area of cone $z=1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ above the plane $x+2z+1=0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Write a double integral for surface area of cone $z=1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ above the plane $x+2z+1=0$.

First I started with finding projection of these two in $xOy$ plane: $-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x}{2}=1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ... which is ellipse
$$\frac{(x-1)^2}{2^2} + \frac{y^2}{(\sqrt{3})^2}=1.$$
Then using formula
$$P=\iint_D \sqrt{1+p^2+q^2}dxdy;$$
I have $z(x,y)=1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ I can easily find partials $p$ and $q$ and I get $\sqrt{2}$ for the $P=\int\int_D \sqrt{2}dxdy$.

Now the area over which the integration is done $D$:

Since it is ellipse I put elliptical coordinates to be:
$x=1+2rcost$ and $y=\sqrt{3}rsint$, where $0\leq r \leq 1$ and $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$ and Jacobian is $2\sqrt{3}r$.

Final, the integral would look like this:
$$P=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{2}2\sqrt{3}rdrdt.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I get the same answer.

Comment: @spinosarus123 great!